# How to save dictionary value into MySQL database tkinter python?

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to save the value stored in dictionary into MySQL database from tkinter GUI The dictionary of value is as follows. Currently 
I am using if else statement for each length which is very lengthy.

```
db=storage.connect()
cursor=db.cursor()
sd1={'AWB Fees': ('122', 'Rupees', '1', '34', '4', '136.00', '8', '10.88'), 
    'Agency Charges': ('122', 'Rupees', '1', '78', '4', '312.00', '8', 
    '24.96'),'AWB': ('122', 'Rupees', '1', '34', '4', '136.00', '8', 
    '10.88')}
length=len(sd1)

y = (sd1.keys())

if (length==1):
    za = ((tuple(y))[0])
    xa = ((sd1[za])[0])
    xb = ((sd1[za])[1])
    xc = ((sd1[za])[2])
    xd = ((sd1[za])[3])
    xf = ((sd1[za])[4])
    xg = ((sd1[za])[5])
    xh = ((sd1[za])[6])
    xi = ((sd1[za])[7])
    cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO sea_exp_tra_raiselocal_inv_fright_est 
            (rlcn_id,billing_head, sac, currency, ex_rate, rate, value, 
            amount, gst, gst_amnt) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
            (sepmId,za,xa,xb,xc,xd,xf,xg,xh,xi))
else:
    pass
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: Err... Sorry but my cystal ball is out for repair, would you mind explaining what your question actually is ?

Comment: I want to know alternate method to insert sd1 value into MySQL database. Length of sd1 dictionary may goes upto 15.

Comment: Well, just iterate over the dict's items, what's the problem ?

Comment: I don't know how to do so please write the code for above mentioned dictionary sd1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really overcomplicating things. First lets clean up the code:

```
sd1 = {
  'AWB Fees': ('122', 'Rupees', '1', '34', '4', '136.00', '8', '10.88'), 
  'Agency Charges': ('122', 'Rupees', '1', '78', '4', '312.00', '8', '24.96'),
  'AWB': ('122', 'Rupees', '1', '34', '4', '136.00', '8', '10.88')
  }

sql = """
  INSERT INTO sea_exp_tra_raiselocal_inv_fright_est 
  (rlcn_id,billing_head, sac, currency, ex_rate, rate, value, amount, gst, gst_amnt) 
  VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
"""

key = list(d.keys())[0]    
values = (sepmId, key,) + sd1[key]
cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

now all you have to do is to iterate over `sd1.items()` (which yields key,value pairs):

```
sd1 = {
  'AWB Fees': ('122', 'Rupees', '1', '34', '4', '136.00', '8', '10.88'), 
  'Agency Charges': ('122', 'Rupees', '1', '78', '4', '312.00', '8', '24.96'),
  'AWB': ('122', 'Rupees', '1', '34', '4', '136.00', '8', '10.88')
  }

sql = """
  INSERT INTO sea_exp_tra_raiselocal_inv_fright_est 
  (rlcn_id,billing_head, sac, currency, ex_rate, rate, value, amount, gst, gst_amnt) 
  VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
"""

for key, val in sd1.items():    
    values = (sepmId, key,) + val
    cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome - but really do yourself a favour and do the full official tutorial before trying to write anything more, this will save yourself (and the world...) quite some time.